# What does this CPAN error mean?

Tags: perl, cpan

I would like to install `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip`, so I do

perl -MCPAN -e shell
install CPAN
install IO::Uncompress::Gunzip

and I get

```
cpan[11]> install IO::Uncompress::Gunzip
Running install for module 'IO::Uncompress::Gunzip'
Running make for P/PM/PMQS/IO-Compress-2.046.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/IO-Compress-2.046-d_Y9xt
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----       PMQS/IO-Compress-2.046.tar.gz      ----
    Compress::Raw::Zlib [requires]
    Compress::Raw::Bzip2 [requires]
Shall I follow them and prepend them to the queue
of modules we are processing right now? [yes] 

...

Result: FAIL
Failed 78/86 test programs. 35/328 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  PMQS/IO-Compress-2.046.tar.gz
2 dependencies missing (Compress::Raw::Bzip2,Compress::Raw::Zlib); additionally test harness failed
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports PMQS/IO-Compress-2.046.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 PMQS/IO-Compress-2.046.tar.gz                : make_test NO 2 dependencies missing (Compress::Raw::Bzip2,Compress::Raw::Zlib); additionally test harness failed
```

See full error output at http://pastebin.com/nGc80C8Z

If I try to install `Compress::Raw::Bzip2` and `Compress::Raw::Zlib` I get

```
cpan[12]> install Compress::Raw::Zlib
Running install for module 'Compress::Raw::Zlib'
Running make for P/PM/PMQS/Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.045.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.045-kBMzIh
Could not make: Unknown error
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible

cpan[13]>
```

**Question**

Does anyone what these errors mean, and perhaps how I can install these modules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First error I can spot is `/bin/sh: gcc: command not found`. It is trying to compile binary parts of the libraries and can't find your compiler. You probably need to install GCC.

A lot (if not all) of the subsequent errors are likely side effects of this.

Answer (score 3):

This was helpful to me, but one additional step that wasn't mentioned here that I needed to perform to be able to install a module was to do a clean [MODULE] before retrying the install [MODULE].

Probably not needed to be mentioned for non-noobs to this environment, but I needed it.